# Python variable passing in functions to a menu

Tags: python

I have a function, menu() which creates a menu to navigate and call functions. here is the function.

```
def menu():
    x = raw_input("WOOF! What can POODLE fetch for you? ('--nothing' to exit): ")
    if x == "--nothing":
            sys.exit(0)
    elif x == "--build":
            populateCrawled(toCrawl)
            graph = buildGraph(crawled)
            index = buildIndex(graph)
            ranks = computeRanks(graph)
            menu()
    elif x == "--dump":
            saveFile(index, "index.txt")
            saveFile(graph, "graph.txt")
            saveFile(ranks, "ranks.txt")
            menu()
    elif x == "--restore":
            index = loadFile("index.txt")
            graph = loadFile("graph.txt")
            ranks = loadFile("ranks.txt")
            menu()
    elif x == "--print":
            print graph
            print index
            print ranks
            menu()
    elif x == "--help":
            print "WOOF! POODLE Help Options"
            print "--build     Create the POODLE database"
            print "--dump      Save the POODLE database"
            print "--restore   Retrieve the POODLE database"
            print "--print     Show the POODLE database"
            print "--help      Show this help information"
            menu()
    elif x == "--search":
            search(index, rankablePages)
    else:
            print "Help option not found"
            menu()

seed = raw_input("Please enter the seed URL: ")
testSeed = "https://dunluce.infc.ulst.ac.uk/d11ga2/COM506/AssignmentB/test_index.html"
seed = testSeed
toCrawl=[seed]
crawled, graph, index, rankablePages = [], {}, {}, {}
MAX_DEPTH = 10
menu()
```

these variables and dictionaries are all declared globally but when I say type "--build" it does successfully build but then if I go to type "--print" it shows me 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'graph' referenced before assignment

However if I print these dictionaries immediatly after building then they print fine. It's when menu() is reloaded it loses these values. Should I use a while loop or do I need to do some parameter passing?

Comment: A better way of structuring menus is to store all of the options as keys in a dictionary with the values being the functions that do what the options represent. Then, your whole menu code can be `if option in options: options[option](); else: print "Invalid input!"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that these variables are declared globally doesn't help (although note that you *didn't* actually define `ranks` globally…), because they're *also* declared locally, and the local names hide the global ones.

Whenever you write `spam = eggs` in the body of a function, that makes `spam` into a local variable, and anywhere `spam` appears in the function, it refers to that local variable.

If you want to make something global, but still be able to assign to it, you need a [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement). So:

```
def menu():
    global graph, index, ranks
    # the rest of your code
```

---

But as usual, a better solution is to stop using global variables.

One option create a *class* to hold your state, make `menu` a method of that class, and make `graph` and friends attributes of the class's instances.

But there's an even simpler option here. The only reason you need these variables to be global is because `menu` is calling itself recursively to simulate a loop. That's already a bad thing to do in Python, for other reasons. (For example, if you go through the menu about 999 times, you're going to get a recursion error.) If you just use a loop instead of trying to fake it, you can just use  local variables:

```
def menu(graph, index, ranks):
    while True:
        # the rest of your code except the menu() calls

# ...
crawled, graph, index, rankablePages = [], {}, {}, {}
menu(graph, index, ranks)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare graph (and any other variable that menu should use externally) as a global:

```
def menu():
    global graph

    #rest of the code
```

you can read more about globals [here](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php)